# How to solve expression must have a constant value error in IAR?

Tags: c++, c, iar

I get the compile error: `"expression must have a constant value"`, even though size is a constant. where is my fault ı can't find it??

```
 void foo(int n)
    {
    int x[n];
    int i = 5;
    if (i == 0)
    i--;
    x[i] = 5; //OK, since i is 4
    }
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Maybe VLAs are not supported.

Comment: No, the size is not constant.

Comment: You should remove the `c++` tag because you mentioned that you're using C89.

Answer (score 0):

C89 doesn't have variable length arrays, so

this line is wrong:

```
int x[n];
```

It depends on the function parameter `n` which is not a compile-time constant.

You could replace the raw array with a `malloc`:

```
int* x = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );
```

Comment: It's also specific to IAR compiler running in C89 dialect mode (or with VLA not allowed).

Comment: ı try to compile this code in IAR WORKBENCH for static analysis . ıt support C89

Comment: @Serapmirage if this solves your issue, you should accept the Answer so others can find it more easily.